# LiClipse Dark editor color (white on yellow)

Tags: liclipse

In LiClipse when you mark a variable the color changes to white on yellow background making it impossible to see.

[image]

I found where I can change the colors:

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Color Teheme -> LiClipse Dark

However I could not find where this color is stored (the yellow background).
Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The related color keys are `occurrenceIndication` and `writeOccurrenceIndication`.

Note that you have to `Apply` after you change the colors.

Still, it's strange that you got that color there as that's not the default, so, maybe you can try to `Restore Defaults`, reselect the `LiClipse Dark theme` and then `Apply` to see if it fixes itself.

Comment: Both occuranceIndication and writeOccurrenceIndication is purple. 
Under Appearance I have selected "Theme: Dark" and "Color and Font theme: Default (current)"

Comment: That's rather odd (I can't reproduce your problem here) -- my guess is that you have that preference recorded (in something as Oomph) and it's overriding the color from the theme theme... you can edit the occurrence annotation color directly (in `General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations`).